# Trying to create a page that if it's the first time logging in checks against a plain text password else checks against a hashed pass (php)

Tags: php, mysql, hash, password-hash

Dang that title is bad.

I am working on a site where a bunch of users are imported by use of a CSV file. This CSV file includes first name, last name, email etc. Before the file is uploaded to the DB I am running it through a program that takes the last name and appends the last 4 digits of a 7 digit number in the CSV and is assigning it to the password value. When a user logs in for the first time it redirects to a page where they enter a new password which gets hashed and stored in the DB using the  password_hash function. It then redirects them to the home page.

On the sign in page it first checks against the DB with the plain text password they entered (I know this is a terrible way of doing it and I'm trying to find another way to do this... Leave your answers to this as well!) If that returns no results it then query's the DB for the hashed pass and stores that in a variable. Then I run the password_verify function and it fails even when I KNOW I entered in the right pass. I var_dump(ed) the hashed var and echoed the pass entered run through the password_hash function. They don't match and I don't know why. Here is the relevant code.

```
    if (!empty($_POST)){  
    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //region prepare the mysqli statement and run it
    //Prepare the query
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, Lname, password FROM users WHERE Lname = ? AND password = ?");

    //Bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Lname, $pass);

    //Run the query
    $stmt->execute();

    //Get results
    $results = $stmt->get_result();

    //Make results usable
    $row = $results->fetch_object();
        //endregion

    //check to make sure results were returned and stores user id into session variable if true
    if (!empty ($row)){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row->id;
        unset($_POST);
         header('Location: home.php');   
        }elseif (empty ($row)){

      $hasho=$con->query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE Lname = "' .$Lname. '"');
    $hash = $hasho->fetch_object();

    $passh = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if ($passh == $hash) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row->id;
    unset($_POST);
     header('Location: home.php');  
}
else {
    echo "Invalid credentials";
}
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid with this code.

Thank you!

Comment: if ($passh == $hash) change to if ($passh == $hash->password) i have not try your code yet. But what object you compare

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the function password_hash() to verify a password, because of the salt which will be randomly choosen.

```
$passh = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if ($passh == $hash) { // those hashes are never comparable
```

Instead you should use the password_verify() function to check the password:

```
if password_verify($pass, $hash) {
```

Comment: @user3772307 - That happens, it's part of being a developer :-)